# How to use jquery html attributes with Angular2?

Tags: angular, jquery-plugins

I have some library, that requires me to add the following tag to my image:

```
data-zoom-image
```

When I am adding this to my image:

```
<img class="larger-picture" [src]="'images/'+item.picture" align="middle" data-zoom-image="'images/'+item.picture"/>
```

Which throws me an error of:

> Can't bind to 'zoom-image' since it isn't a known native property

How can I fix this?

To be more precise: the library that I want to use is [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[attr.xxx]** syntax to bind attributes to HTML controls as shown here.

```
<img class="larger-picture" [src]="'images/'+item.picture" align="middle" 
[attr.data-zoom-image]="'images/'+item.picture"/>
```

Official docs : - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html